# How to add Object ID to any local in Visual Studio 2015 without crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need to check if the object at hand is the same as it was at the previous iteration.

So I tried to use *Make Object ID* feature in Visual Studio 2015 Professional (with *Administrator mode* and without it):

[image]

[image]

The result:

[image]

What should I check? Is there any restriction that prevents me from using that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Use a ***watch*** instead of a *local*
- Update your Visual Studio 2015 to Update 3 - it seems they fixed the *local* issue as well